# Fragment "F1" cannot be spread here as objects of type "Node" can never be of type "Store"

Tags: reactjs, graphql, relay

I have written below code :

On Certain User Action below method is called :

```
handleFolderClicked = (topic, parent) => {
    console.log('Main : handleFolderClicked called : ', parent);
    this.props.relay.setVariables({
      parentFolder: parent,
      email: loginEmail
    });
  }

Main = Relay.createContainer(Main, {
  initialVariables: {
    pageSize: pageSize,
    email: loginEmail,
    parentFolder: parentFolder,
  },
  fragments: {
    store: () => Relay.QL`
      fragment on Store {
        id,
        fileConnection(first:999, email:$email, parentFolder:$parentFolder) {
          ${DirectoryListing.getFragment('files')},
        }
        users {
          email,
        }
      }
    `,
  }
});
export default Main;
```

On the time of page load its working fine and fetching results but when value of parentFolder is changed using setVariables, it throws above error.

An insight might be useful and appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had this error and I solved with something like this:

`Store` has to implement Relay's `Node` interface, meaning that it has to provide an `id: ID!` field, and if you do a node query using the returned ID, your `Store` has to be returned.

In my case I named my root object `viewer` of type `Viewer`; so after implementing the `Node` interface, this query has to work:

```
{
  viewer {
    id
  }
}
```

Which returns:

```
{
  "data": {
    "viewer": {
      "id": "Vmlld2VyOk5vbmU="
    }
  }
}
```

Now if I use that ID to run a node Query, the viewer has to be returned. So for the query:

```
{
  node(id: "Vmlld2VyOk5vbmU=") {
    id,
    __typename
  }
}
```

This should be the result:

```
{
  "data": {
    "node": {
      "id": "Vmlld2VyOk5vbmU=",
      "__typename": "Viewer"
    }
  }
}
```

Replace all occurrences of `viewer`/`Viewer` with `store`/`Store` and it should work.