# Fragment cannot be spread here as objects of type "X" can never be of type "Y"

Tags: reactjs, graphql, relay

In this case, type "X" is `Application` and type "Y" is type "Node" - I can see *why this is happening*, but my understanding of Relay isn't enough to understand how to fix it. The query generated by Relay is

```
query {
    node(id: $some_id) {
        ...F0
    }
}

fragment F0 on Application {
    ...
}
```

I have a schema that looks like

```
query {
    application { 
        /* kind of a generic endpoint for fetching lists, etc */
        invites(token: $token) {
            name
        }
    }
    viewer { /* the current user */ }
}
```

I'm trying to fetch a specific invite from outside a session (`viewer` is `null`).

I've tried

```
const application = Relay.QL`query { application }`
...
<Route ... queries={{ application }}/>
...
Relay.createContainer(Component, {
    initialValues: { token: null },
    fragments: {
        application: () => {
            fragment on Application {
                invites(token: $token) {
                    ...
                }
            }
        }
    }
})
```

which gives me the error

fragment "F0" cannot be spread here as objects of type "Node" can never be of type "Application" - or something to that effect.

I'm a little confused, because if I were to write a raw query and run it through GraphQL directly

```
query {
    application {
        invites(token: "asdasdasd") {
            edges {
                node {
                    name
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

it gives me what I'm looking for...

In the backend, my graph is defined like

```
export const Application = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Application',
  fields: () => ({
    id: {
      type: GraphQLString,
      resolve: () => 'APPLICATION_ID'
    },
    invites: {
        type: InviteConnectionType,
        args: connectionArgs,
        resolve: (application, args) => {
            ...
        } 
    }
  })
})

export default new GraphQLSchema({
  query: new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'query',
  fields: {
    node: nodeField,
    application: {
      type: Application,
      resolve: (root, args, ctx) => {
        return Promise.resolve({})
      }
    }
  }
})
```

I've been looking at questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42552256/fragment-f1-cannot-be-spread-here-as-objects-of-type-node-can-never-be-of-ty) and some [issues on the Relay github](https://github.com/facebook/relay/issues/1409), but it's not clear to me how I should implement `nodeInterface`.

edit: the short-long of the current `nodeInterface` code is

```
export const {
  nodeInterface,
  nodeField
} = nodeDefinitions(
  (globalId) => {
    const { type, id } = fromGlobalId(globalId)
    return db[type].findById(id)
  },
  (obj) => {
    const name = obj.$modelOptions.name.singular
    return types[name]
  }
)
```

Application is not a db model, however, just a generic interface to fetch data through. I've tried checking to see if `type === 'Application'`, and returning null (although I see why that doesn't work), returning `Application` (the GraphQLObject), but that doesn't work... not really sure where to go from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You need to automatically generate an unique global id for a GraphQL
  type that you want to refetch.
- In `nodeInterface` you tell GraphQL
  how to map the id to the corresponding GraphQL object.
- By the given server-side object `nodeInterface` identifies the GraphQL type.

Below is simplified example how it may look like with Application:

```
// nodeInterface.
var {nodeInterface, nodeField} = nodeDefinitions(
  (globalId) => {
    var {type, id} = fromGlobalId(globalId);

    // The mapping from globalId to actual object id and type.
    console.log('globalId:', id);
    console.log('type:', type);

    if (type === 'Application') {
      // getApplication is your db method to retrieve Application object.
      // With id you could also retrieve a specific db object.
      return getApplication();
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  },
  (obj) => {
    // Note that instanceof does an identity check on the prototype object, so it can be easily fooled.
    if (obj instanceof Application) {
      return ApplicationType;
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  },
);

// Application.
export const ApplicationType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Application',
  fields: () => ({
    // Auto-generated, globally defined id.
    id: globalIdField('Application'),
    _id: {
      type: GraphQLString,
      resolve: () => 'APPLICATION_ID'
    },
    invites: {
        type: InviteConnectionType,
        args: connectionArgs,
        resolve: (application, args) => {
            ...
        } 
    }
  }),
  // Declaring nodeInterface.
  interfaces: [nodeInterface]
});
```

Note that during the initial fetch `nodeInterface` is not even executed, so if `nodeInterface` is returning nothing there won’t be errors at the initial fetch. If that doesn’t make sense or you’re still struggling you can post a link to the repo, I’ll look into it.

Comment: yeah I sort of figured I needed to implement `nodeInterface`, however I'm not really sure how to... check my edit.

Comment: Sorry misunderstood. In `nodeInterface` you basically need to map globally defined ids into data objects, so that Relay would be able to fetch an object. I think this https://github.com/entria/graphql-dataloader-boilerplate/blob/8d661425538e7881f8eb12437929aba77d4cfbba/src/interface/NodeInterface.js complete example would be helpful.

Comment: But what about something that isn't /technically/ an object with edges and relations, just an interface for other things - like application in this case. I've already tried (more or less) what I think implementing nodeinterface for application would look like.

Comment: That must be the problem, you should return db object, I’ve edited my answer above.

Answer (score 1):

To give an update on this, I was on the right path.

The current `nodeDefinitions` I had just needed a little extra:

```
nodeDefinitions(
  (globalId) => {
    const { type, id } = fromGlobalId(globalId)

    if (type === 'Application') {
      return Promise.resolve(Application)
    }

    return db[type].findById(id)
  },
  (obj) => {
    if (obj.$modelOptions) {
      /* sequelize object */
      const name = obj.$modelOptions.name.singular
      return types[name]
    } else if (obj.name === 'Application') {
      return Application
    }

    return null
  }
)
```

I'm not sure if this is the best way to do it, but it seems to do the trick. The gist is that, if the type of node that I want to be returned is `Application`, I return the GraphQL object - `{ ... name: "Application" ... }` we'll use the `name` field from this in the next step (the second callback in `nodeDefinitions`) to just re-return `Application`. I think you could return a "custom" object or something else - it doesn't matter so long as you return something unique that you can define a mapping from to a `GraphQLObject` type (required for the second callback).